# How to add a conditional filter for drupal's view?

Tags: drupal, drupal-views

Only apply the filter when there is `filter=1` in the query string,

has anyone managed to do this kind of **conditional** filter with drupal?

Answer (score 1):

For some reason I think there's something wrong with your approach, but since there's no specifics, I can't really give my opinion.

Answering your question: you can try implementing `hook_views_query_alter()`, testing if the parameter `filter` equals 1 and, if so, removing the condition added by the filter.